# anyway to put <?php echo do_shortcode(“[shortcode]”); ?> inside a $outprint=sprintf()

Tags: php, shortcode

wanna put 
`<?php echo do_shortcode("[shortcode]"); ?>`
inside et_pb_title_container shown as below

```
<div%3$s class="et_pb_module et_pb_post_title %2$s%4$s%8$s%10$s%11$s">
            %5$s
            %9$s
            %6$s
            <div class="et_pb_title_container">
                %1$s
                <div class="entry-content">
            </div>
            %7$s
            </div>
```

please help, not quite understanding php, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use `do_shortcode()` in `sprintf()` like any other value:

```
$output = sprintf( '<div>%s</div>', do_shortcode( '[shortcode]' ) );
```